# Java youtube API error 403 Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, api-key, youtube-data-api

i have an issue with the following code : i'm trying to use the youtube API v3 to run the simple geolocation code (first code) but i keep getting the service error 403 Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded Continued use requires signup.

I have a valid key stored in the youtube.properties file and the youtube data API is activated on the google.console.developpers page. I don't understand the issue because when i run an even simpler code (2nd code) which uses the same authentication system, it works.

first code : doesn't work

```
 /*
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.util.Joiner;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.GeoPoint;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Thumbnail;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * This sample lists videos that are associated with a particular keyword and are in the radius of
 *   particular geographic coordinates by:
 *
 * 1. Searching videos with "youtube.search.list" method and setting "type", "q", "location" and
 *   "locationRadius" parameters.
 * 2. Retrieving location details for each video with "youtube.videos.list" method and setting
 *   "id" parameter to comma separated list of video IDs in search result.
 *
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya
 */
public class GeolocationSearch {

    /**
     * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
     * contains the developer's API key.
     */
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
     * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
     *
     * @param args command line args.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the developer key from the properties file.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = GeolocationSearch.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            properties.load(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                    + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
            // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
            // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
            // the interface and provide a no-op function.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-geolocationsearch-sample").build();

            // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
            String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

            // Prompt the user to enter location coordinates.
            String location = getInputLocation();

            // Prompt the user to enter a location radius.
            String locationRadius = getInputLocationRadius();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

            // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
            // non-authenticated requests. See:
            // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(queryTerm);
            search.setLocation(location);
            search.setLocationRadius(locationRadius);

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // As a best practice, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            //search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");

            search.setFields("items(id/videoId)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (searchResultList != null) {

                // Merge video IDs
                for (SearchResult searchResult : searchResultList) {
                    videoIds.add(searchResult.getId().getVideoId());
                }
                Joiner stringJoiner = Joiner.on(',');
                String videoId = stringJoiner.join(videoIds);

                // Call the YouTube Data API's youtube.videos.list method to
                // retrieve the resources that represent the specified videos.
                YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, recordingDetails").setId(videoId);
                VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

                List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();

                if (videoList != null) {
                    prettyPrint(videoList.iterator(), queryTerm);
                }
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
     */
    private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
            inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter location coordinates and return the user-specified coordinates.
     */
    private static String getInputLocation() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter location coordinates (example: 37.42307,-122.08427): ");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "37.42307,-122.08427" as a default.
            inputQuery = "37.42307,-122.08427";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a location radius and return the user-specified radius.
     */
    private static String getInputLocationRadius() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter a location radius (examples: 5km, 8mi):");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "5km" as a default.
            inputQuery = "5km";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
     * title, video ID, location, and thumbnail.
     *
     * @param iteratorVideoResults Iterator of Videos to print
     *
     * @param query Search query (String)
     */
    private static void prettyPrint(Iterator<Video> iteratorVideoResults, String query) {

        System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
        System.out.println(
                "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
        System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

        if (!iteratorVideoResults.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
        }

        while (iteratorVideoResults.hasNext()) {

            Video singleVideo = iteratorVideoResults.next();

            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();
            GeoPoint location = singleVideo.getRecordingDetails().getLocation();

            System.out.println(" Video Id" + singleVideo.getId());
            System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println(" Location: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
            System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
}*
```

2nd code, the one that works even though it uses the same authentication method:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Thumbnail;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Print a list of videos matching a search term.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Walker
 */
public class Search {

    /**
     * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
     * contains the developer's API key.
     */
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
     * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
     *
     * @param args command line args.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the developer key from the properties file.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            properties.load(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                    + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
            // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
            // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
            // the interface and provide a no-op function.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

            // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
            String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

            // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
            // non-authenticated requests. See:
            // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(queryTerm);

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
     */
    private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
            inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
     * title, video ID, and thumbnail.
     *
     * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
     *
     * @param query Search query (String)
     */
    private static void prettyPrint(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {

        System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
        System.out.println(
                "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
        System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

        if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
        }

        while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

            SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
            ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

            // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
            // item will not contain a video ID.
            if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

                System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
                System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
                System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API key must be applied to each YouTube Service

Probably works:

```
search.setKey(apiKey);
SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
```

Probably doesn't work:

```
VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();
```

Missing

```
listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
```

Note I don't have the power to test Java so this is kind of a guess.

Comment: That worked, i don't know why google would give out code that doesn't work as a sample that is supposed to help people understand how the API works though.  Anyway thank you very much

Comment: If its a google official tutorial that you are following that doesn't work please give me the link I will report it they should fix it.   remember to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: The code i used must be official since it's the code samples provided with the youtube API. You can find all the code online, the specific sample that i had trouvle with is : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_location

Comment: I logged it as a bug also going to see if I can find someone at Google to ping about it I don't have any YouTube devs in my contact list.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8839&thanks=8839

Comment: Okay thank you, i'm actually a student so i don't know anything about reporting bugs to huge companies like google and i don't have any professional contacts either